# How to sum row values by category

Tags: vba, excel

So I have got the following table in Excel for example (it actually has 100+ rows):

```
Alfa     10
Beta     5
Alfa     10
Beta     5
Gama     15
```

What I would like to do is SUM values by the name (category) using VBA Macro, so I can display it somewhere in the Sheet like this:

```
AlfaTotal     20
BetaTotal     10
GamaTotal     15
```

I have tried using For Each function but am not able to get to the values. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is VBA a must? You have several options in plain Excel that will do this for you, like CountIf and Pivot tables.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a must, since it has to be a Button and when it's clicked, the SUM will be calculated.

Comment: Having the results automatically calculated with an Excel formula and just showing/hiding them with the button is not an option?

Comment: You could still use a Pivot Table.  And have your button execute the `Refresh` option.

Comment: I do know all the other options, however it has to be a VBA, as it is for creating a dashboard with many other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dictionary is a common method. The below handles blanks in range, also if only 1 item present. It doesn't need an `.Exists` test as simply adds to any existing value by direct access. Also, writes arrays of keys, items out in one go.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTotals()
    Dim dict As Object, arr(), i As Long, lastRow As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")       '<==source data
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Select Case lastRow
        Case 1
            ReDim arr(1, 1): arr(1, 1) = .Range("A1:B1").Value
        Case Else
            arr = .Range("A1:B" & lastRow).Value
        End Select
    End With

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 2)
        End If
    Next
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A1").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys)
        .Range("B1").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Results:

[image: data]

Comment: Why the downvote on a helpful answer and a more efficient code example? #Salty

Comment: Good point to treat the zero and one item case, too +1). -  BTW, unexplained downvoting (of efficient code) isn't helpful for anybody

Comment: @T.M. Thanks for that.

Comment: It's a nice and more efficient solution, I have added +1 :)

Comment: Is this now answered?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how many categories you'll have before trying to sum them, something like this could be a solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim d As Object
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim s As String, key_value As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim num As Long

    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    Set r = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Range("A2"), Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For Each c In r
        key_value = CStr(c)
        num = CLng(c.Offset(0, 1))

        If d.Exists(key_value) Then
            d(key_value) = d(key_value) + num
        Else
            d.Add Key:=key_value, Item:=num
        End If
    Next c

    For Each v In d
        s = s & CStr(v) & vbTab & CStr(d(v)) & vbLf
    Next v

    MsgBox prompt:=s, Title:="Summation", Buttons:=vbInformation
End Sub
```

If you know what categories you'll have in advance, just making some `sumif` formulas based on those would probably be simpler.

Comment: Scripting Dictionary should be in inverted commas  like this :-                  Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Comment: Oh, yeah, I just quickly threw together something and didn't really test it after switching to late binding. Thanks for the correction! @anthony